# How to unhide an html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check if the content in `#textd` is not empty and that it contains more than 150 chars. If so, I send its content to another web page, if not I display an error message relative to the context. I'm doing this with these codes:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVEqe/)

HTML code:

```
  <a href="#" id="r"><span>AFD</span></a>

  <div class="ooo" hidden>
      <h4 id="titled">FOPJG?</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
       <p id="textd"></p>
  </div>

  <button id="submitd">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$("#r").click(function () {
    $(".ooo").prop("hidden", false);
});

$("#submitd").click(function () {
    if (!$("#textd").empty() && $("#textd").length() < 150) {
        var str = $("#textd").text();
        window.location.replace("foo?d="+str);
    } else {
        if (!$("#textd").empty() && $("#textd").length() > 150) {
            $("#titled").html("FOPJG?<small style='color:red;'>not under 150 chars.</small>");
        } else {
            $("#titled").html("FOPJG?<small style='color:red;'>ABVQS.</small>");
        }
    }
});
```

The issue here, is that when I click on that submit button, the `.ooo` is not displayed. I've also another question, does this implementation work correctly relative to the above algorithm's description?

Comment: jQuery exposes `.click` not `.onclick` (onclick is native js API)

Comment: click is an event that jQuery can attach logic to. onclick is an html attribute that will fire off its value (which is JS) upon a click event.

Comment: @TravisJ, I have tried that but it still the same.

Comment: Check your error console.  Here, `$('a').onclick()` yields `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onclick'` because, as Travis J points out, jQuery doesn't provide `.onclick()`.  Try `.on('click', function)` or `.click(function)`

Comment: What kinds of error messages appear on the browser console log?

Comment: also, can you set `hidden` to false? You may have to use `.removeAttr` instead. (I'm not up to speed on HTML5's hidden attribute...)

Comment: So, HTML doesn't take `hidden="false"` but jQuery is smart enough to just remove that attribute when you set it to false, so that's not the issue.

Comment: `#textd` is a `<p>` element. If you're expecting user input you need to use `<input />`. If the content is built elsewhere and just displayed in `#textd` you probably should be running this check there.

Comment: `#titred !== #titled`

Comment: @DACrosby, I'm filling that dynamically.

Comment: @Paul, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Also, `.empty()` doesn't return true/false the way you're expecting. Use `.text().length` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things:

- You should use `style="display:none;"` instead of the `hidden`attribute. It's just more standard. Further, you should use an external style sheets instead for all of the styles, but that's another battle.
- Your if/else logic is a bit faulty: `.empty()` removes everything from the element - it will not return true/false the way you're expecting. Use `.text().length` instead.
- You will likely also want to use `return false;` (or `e.preventDefault();`) so the links don't go anywhere.

So, here goes:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="r"><span>AFD</span></a>

<div class="ooo" style="display:none;">
    <h4 id="titled">FOPJG?</h4>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="textd">[ ... ]</p>
</div>

<button id="submitd">Submit</button>
```

jQuery

```
$("#r").click(function () {
    $(".ooo").show();
    return false;
});

$("#submitd").click(function () {
    if ($("#textd").text().length == 0) {
        $("#titled").html("FOPJG?<small style='color:red;'> It's Empty</small>");
    } else if ($("#textd").text().length < 150) {
        $("#titled").html("FOPJG?<small style='color:red;'> Length is under 150 chars.</small>");
    } else if ($("#textd").text().length) {
        $("#titled").html("FOPJG?<small style='color:red;'> Length is over or exactly 150 chars.</small>");
    }
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvVZ9/1/)

Comment: @Serlite - Good catch, nice edit. Thanks! I suppose you could use `!$("#textd").text().length` as well, since 0 == false. Saving a massive 4 characters, joy!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `visibility: hidden` instead of html hidden tag so you can change its property easily in js